# How to use mmap to allocate a memory in heap?

Tags: c, memory-management, heap-memory, mmap

Just the question stated, how can I use `mmap()` to allocate a memory in heap? This is my only option because `malloc()` is not a reentrant function.

Comment: If your `malloc()` isn't reentrant, wouldn't it be easier to just write a wrapper with a lock instead of rolling your own entire memory system?

Comment: mmapped memory is neither heap nor stack, so I have no clue what you're asking here.

Comment: Locking cannot make a non-reentrant function reentrant. It can only make non-thread-safe functions thread-safe. Reentrant is a **much stronger** condition.

Comment: @Carl, if he wants it to operate in signal handlers, a lock isn't going to be good enough.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Why do you need reentrancy? The only time it's needed is for calling a function from a signal handler; otherwise, thread-safety is just as good. Both `malloc` and `mmap` are thread-safe. Neither is async-signal-safe per POSIX. In practice, `mmap` probably works fine from a signal handler, but the whole idea of allocating memory from a signal handler is a very bad idea.

If you want to use `mmap` to allocate anonymous memory, you can use `MAP_ANON`/`MAP_ANONYMOUS`.

```
p = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
```

At one point this was not strictly portable, and systems differed in which spelling they supported so you should write preprocessor conditionals to use whichever is available, but POSIX has since adopted both spellings as standard.

The traditional but ugly version, from long ago before `MAP_ANON` was a thing, is:

```
int fd = open("/dev/zero", O_RDWR);
p = mmap(0, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
close(fd);
```

Note that `MAP_FAILED`, not `NULL`, is the code for failure.

Comment: Actually I need to allocate a memory in the signal handler. So basically I need a reentrant implementation for this. I saw the malloc_r and free_r which was created for reentrancy but only available for my compiler. Thanks

Comment: Then there's no conformant way to allocate memory, but `mmap` will "probably" work. It would be a lot better to fix the design that makes it necessary to allocate memory from a signal handler. Normally a signal handler should either do nothing or just set a single flag variable or write a byte to a pipe.

Comment: By the way, since "do nothing" probably was not clear, a "do nothing" signal handler is useful with the `SA_RESTART` flag omitted to interrupt syscalls. Setting a do-nothing signal handler to interrupt syscalls and and using `pthread_kill` to send the signal to a particular thread is a way to "roll your own" thread cancellation without the unfixable resource leak issues `pthread_cancel` leads to. It can also be useful with just a single thread if you set a timer/alarm to generate the signal, to set timeouts for syscalls.

Comment: The most portable version is probably not to open `/dev/zero` but to use `shm_open` instead, which internally does about the same thing but doesn't require your file system with special files to be up.

Comment: Is `MAP_PRIVATE` valid with shared memory obtained via `shm_open`? I suppose so, since I couldn't find anywhere it's explicitly prohibited, but this seems counter-intuitive.

Comment: @R: And for the deallocation? Do I need to call the munmap? like this `munmap( p, 0 ) ?

Comment: @sasayins: Not like that. You must pass the length of the mapping to `munmap`; you can't just pass 0.

Comment: oh gee, I guess I need to re-implement. because what I did was I created a malloc and free hooks, I used mmap to __wrap_malloc and I used munmap to __wrap_free.

Comment: Just store the size at the beginning of the `mmap`-allocated block, and return a pointer to the byte just after where the size is stored. Then freeing the block is as easy as backing up to read the size and passing the new pointer and size to `munmap`.

Comment: Sorry for the late reaction: I found your question by google, exactly because I want to find a way to allocate dynamical memory from a signal handler.

Comment: FYI the resolution of [Austin Group issue 850](https://www.austingroupbugs.net/view.php?id=850) standardized `MAP_ANON` (and `MAP_ANONYMOUS` alias) for future edition of POSIX.

Comment: Accessing `/dev/` can be problematic if you're writing library code which gets used in a chroot environment.  [This](https://lo.calho.st/posts/black-magic-buffer/) page suggests `syscall(__NR_memfd_create, name, flags)` instead, but I don't know how portable that is and I came here looking for an alternative (and `-1` will do, thanks!).  Though I see in comments `shm_open()`, too.  Will investigate.

Comment: @sh1: Yes, but that's already solved by `MAP_ANON` being accepted into the standard and already universal anyway. memfd on the other hand is Linux-specific and creates a shared memory object that persists until there are no references to it, which is NOT what's wanted here.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Good to know.  This is, after all, 12 years on.  Does the answer need an update regarding which method is most portable?

Comment: @sh1: Good idea. I forgot folks might not read all the comments. Does my edit look good?

Comment: Yeah, looks good to me.

Answer (score 10):

#### Make a simple [slab allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocator)

---

Although allocating memory in a signal handler<sup>1</sup> does seem like something best avoided, it certainly can be done.

No, you can't directly use malloc(). If you want it to be in the heap then mmap won't work either.

My suggestion is that you make a special-purpose [slab allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocator) based on malloc.

Decide exactly what size of object you want and preallocate some number of them. Allocate them initially with malloc() and save them for concurrent use later. There are intrinsically reentrant queue-and-un-queue functions that you can use to obtain and release these blocks. If they only need to be managed from the signal handler then even that isn't necessary.

Problem solved!

---

<sup>1. And if you are not doing that then it seems like you have an embedded system or could just use malloc().</sup>