# mmap substitute for malloc

Tags: c, assembly, x86, malloc, mmap

I need to find a way to use mmap instead of malloc. How is this possible? (I am not using libc only syscalls) And yes brk() is possible. I used sbrk() but realized its not sys-call... (x86 inline assembly)

I've been looking around and saw this: [How to use mmap to allocate a memory in heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779188/how-to-use-mmap-to-allocate-a-memory-in-heap) But it didn't help for me, because I had a segfault.

Basically, all I want to do a create 3 slabs of memory for storing characters.

Say,

```
char * x = malloc(1000);
char * y = malloc(2000);
char * z = malloc(3000);
```

How is this possible with mmap and how to free it later with munmap?

Comment: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sbrk.2.html is a syscall, but a deprecated one.

Comment: the glibc `malloc` uses `mmap` if appropriate (for example, if the amount of bytes to allocate is beyond a certain threshold)

Comment: taken from the malloc man page:  Normally, malloc() allocates memory from the heap, and adjusts the size of the heap as required, using sbrk(2).  When allocating blocks of memory larger than MMAP_THRESHOLD bytes, the glibc malloc() implementation allocates the memory as a  private  anonymous  mapping  using  mmap(2). MAP_THRESHOLD  is  128  kB  by  default,  but is adjustable using mallopt(3).  Allocations performed using mmap(2)  are  unaffected  by the RLIMIT_DATA resource limit (see getrlimit(2)).

Comment: How are you not using libc? mmap and malloc are libc calls.

Comment: @LtWorf: `malloc` is indeed a standard `libc` function, but `mmap` is a system call, that can be called without any library.... like Flexo's answer shows....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you carefully read the [mmap(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) man page? I recommend reading it several times.

Notice that you can only ask the kernel [thru `mmap` etc...] to manage memory aligned to and multiple of the page size `sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)`  which is often 4096 bytes (and I am supposing that in my answer).

Then you might do:

```
  size_t page_size =  sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
  assert (page_size == 4096); // otherwise this code is wrong

  // 1000 bytes fit into 1*4096
  char *x = mmap (NULL, page_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, 
                  MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, (off_t)0);
  if (x == MMAP_FAILED) perror("mmap x"), exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

  // 2000 bytes fit into 1*4096
  char *y = mmap (NULL, page_size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, 
                  MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, (off_t)0);
  if (y == MMAP_FAILED) perror("mmap y"), exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
```

later to free the memory, use

```
  if (munmap(x, page_size))
     perror("munmap x"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

etc

If you want to allocate 5Kbytes, you'll need two pages (because 5Kbytes < 2*4096 and 5Kbytes > 1*4096) i.e. `mmap(NULL, 2*page_size,` ...

Actually, all  of your `x`, `y`, `z` takes only 8000 bytes and could fit into two, not three, pages... But then you could only `munmap` that memory together.

Be aware that `mmap` is a system call which might be quite expensive. `malloc` implementations take care to avoid calling it too often, that is why they manage previously `free`-d zones to reuse them later (in further `malloc`-s) without any syscall. In practice, most `malloc` implementations manage differently big allocations (e.g. more than a megabyte), which are often `mmap`-ed at `malloc` and `munmap`-ed at `free` time.... You could study the source code of some `malloc`. The one from [MUSL Libc](http://musl-libc.org/) might be easier to read than the Glibc `malloc`.

BTW, the file `/proc/1234/maps` is showing you the memory map of process of pid 1234. Try also `cat /proc/self/maps` in a terminal, it shows the memory map of that `cat` process.

Comment: should it be "sysconf(_SC_PAGESIZE)"?

Answer (score 4):

You can call `mmap` to make an anonymous mapping in x86 asm with something like:

```
    mov eax, 192    ; mmap
    xor ebx, ebx    ; addr   = NULL
    mov ecx, 4096   ; len    = 4096
    mov edx, $7     ; prot   = PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC
    mov esi, $22    ; flags  = MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS
    mov edi, -1     ; fd     = -1 (Ignored for MAP_ANONYMOUS)
    xor ebp, ebp    ; offset = 0 (4096*0) (Ignored for MAP_ANONYMOUS)
    int $80         ; make call (There are other ways to do this too)
```